# NoMethodError in AuthenticationsController#create undefined method `RandomString' for String:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid, omniauth

I follow this tutorial for install omniauth in devise+mongoid:

https://github.com/fertapric/rails3-mongoid-devise-omniauth/wiki/OmniAuth-Installation-Tutorial

I have devise 1.4.5 + omniauth 0.3.0 + rails 3.1.0.

I have in my **devise.rb** the next information:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, 'My_CONSUMER_KEY', 'MY_CONSUMER_SECRET', :scope => 'user_hometown, user_about_me, email'
```

In the tutorial, this configuration have that create a initializers/omniauth.rb file.

When I come back of facebook callback I catch this error:

```
NoMethodError in AuthenticationsController#create

undefined method `RandomString' for String:Class

app/models/user.rb:39:in `apply_trusted_services'
app/models/user.rb:23:in `apply_omniauth'
app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:33:in `create_new_omniauth_user'
app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

I have create too a file in **lib/string_extensions.rb** with this code:

```
module StringExtensions
  def self.included(base) 
    String.extend StringExtensions::ClassMethods
  end
  module ClassMethods
    RAND_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789"
    def RandomString(len)
      rand_max = RAND_CHARS.size
      ret = ""
      len.times{ ret << RAND_CHARS[rand(rand_max)] }
      ret
    end
  end
end
```

Whats is my problem

Comment: As a note, method names in Ruby should not have capital letters. Constants are `ALL_CAPS`, classes are `CapsFirst`, and methods should be `lower_case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable loading of modules in your `application.rb`

Comment: Thank you, I had enable in config/aplication.rb this:

 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
 require 'string_extensions'
 include StringExtensions
But now I catch the next error in my web page (Is error in web page rendered):

The url is:

 http://localhost:3000/sign_up#_=_
And alert in red color over Sign up form:

Auhtentication FAIL!!

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in `config/initializers` and it would get loaded automatically, otherwise you will have to manually load it from `lib/` using a messy `require`

Comment: Thank you for your response, now the problem is that I catch error: Auhtentication FAIL!! I dont know why now show this error in form in red color

Comment: Sounds like a different question.